# Regclass in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
run_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('file_log_id'::regclass)
```

what does this command do? does it make run_id as auto-increment?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Answer (score 0):

The `nextval` function takes an argument of type `regclass`, that is why you see this type cast from `text` in the expression.

Objects in PostgreSQL are identified by their OID (object identifier) which is an unsigned 4 byte value.

To avoid having to dig out the numeric object ID to refer to a table, view or sequence, the convenience type `regclass` has been created. Its internal representation is the numeric OID, but the type input and output functions convert it from and to the object name.